# Como fazer um "while" do número de linhas de uma 'query'?

Tags: php, mysql

Alguém sabe se naquela função do PHP - `mysql_num_rows` tem com eu fazer um `while` nele? Preciso quebrar o número total de linhas da tabela. Eu tentei fazer:

```
$sql = "select ...";
$query = mysql_qery($sql);
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query);

while(!empty($rows)){

}
```

Tentei o `!isset`, variável `= ""`, variável `= 0` mas ele faz um loop infinito e só pega o primeiro *range* do bloco de linhas da query, também tentei fazer um `for` mas também não deu certo.

já testei com `echo` a variável retorna da tela.

Continua fazendo um loop infinito, preciso que nesse loop ele pegue um range de linhas eu declarei duas variáveis, uma para o

`$inicio = 0;`

e a outra para o limit

`$limit = 100;`

o range seria o bloco entre o inicio e o limit e ao fazer o loop incrementasse o valor do limit no offset, ja tentei fazer:

```
$offset = $offset+$limit;
```

e

```
$offset = $offset+100;
```

mais ele pega só a primeira linhas e faz o loop infinito nessa primeira linha.

Alguém tem uma ideia de como resolver isso?

eu queria alterar a variável $offset toda vez que for fazer o loop o valor seria o valor da variável do $limit que vai ser fixa tem como fazer isso dinamicamente em php

Comment: Pela função mysql_num_rows , você já verificou se está retornando a contagem certinha?

Comment: Primeiro, dá um echo $rows. Se retornou certo o valor, muda teu while: while($rows > 0){

Comment: O que você quer é um `for`, provavelmente e não um `while`. Agora, tá parecendo que é o caso de usar `LIMIT` no SQL se vai usar uma parte só das linhas. Se você quer agrupar as linhas de 10 em 10, por exemplo, ou por cabeçalhos/rodapés a cada N registros, já tem respostas no site sobre isso. Se vai usar para paginação, também tem.

Comment: @daniloeugenio acredito ter finalmente entendido sua pergunta a partir da sua outra pergunta (que é uma duplicata e você deveria remover). Nela você explicou um pouco melhor sobre o que queria. Veja se minha resposta abaixo responde à pergunta.

Comment: @Danilo, conforme comentei na sua pergunta nova, é melhor você [edit] esta aqui e explicar o problema de maneira bem clara, em vez de abrir novas questões sobre o mesmo problema. Procure dar o máximo de detalhes do resultado que quer obter na própria questão, que fica mais fácil da comunidade ajudar.

Answer (score 2):

Faça o seguinte:

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM tabela');
$linhas_afetadas = mysql_num_rows($query);
$limit = 100;

for ($offset = 0; $offset < $linhas_afetadas; $offset += $limit) {
    $query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM tabela LIMIT ' . $limit . ' OFFSET ' . $offset);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_NUM)) {
        // $row é um registro da sua tabela
    }
}
```

No exemplo dado, você vai pegar os registros da DB de `100` em `100`, iterando sobre esses `100` dentro de `while ($row ...) {}`.

`$row` é um array, o qual vai conter um registro retornado pela sua *query*, por iteração. Cada índice do array vai corresponder a uma coluna da sua tabela. Se sua tabela for:

```
+----+----------+-------+-------+
| id | nome     | idade | grupo |
+----+----------+-------+-------+
```

Então `$row` vai conter a seguinte estrutura a cada iteração:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ID
    [1] => NOME
    [2] => IDADE
    [3] => GRUPO
)
```